# Multiplication of 2D arrays, using pointers to pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've been trying to implement a program in C, where i have two 2D arrays (created with pointers) and i have to multiply them (like multiplying matrices) and store the results to a third array. The dimensions of the arrays are given by the user. I've done the code but i'm getting wrong results. Is there something wrong with my formula? I wanted to do the reading and printing with functions.
For example, when i input n = 2, m = 2 and k =2. For each element of the matrix i input

```
A(0)(0) = 1, A(0)(1) = 2, A(1)(0) = 3, A(1)(1) = 4 
and
B(0)(0) = 1,> B(0)(1) = 2, B(1)(0) = 3, B(1)(1) = 4.
```

The output should've been

```
C(0)(0) = 7, C(0)(1) = 10, C(1)(0) = 15 and C(1)(1) = 22.
```

Instead the output is

```
C(0)(0) = 7, C(0)(1) = 10, C(1)(0) = 33, C(1)(1) = 46.
```

I hope it's not hard to understand, i'm not allowed to post an image yet :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **read(int **x, int i, int j);
int **prod(int **x, int **y, int n, int m, int k);
void print(int **x, int r, int c);

int main()
{
int n, m, k, i, j;

printf("Give n, m and k: ");
scanf("%d%d%d", &n, &m, &k);

int **A, **B, **C;

A = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    *(A+i) = (int *)malloc(k*sizeof(int));

B = (int **)malloc(k*sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    *(B+i) = (int *)malloc(m*sizeof(int));

C = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    *(C+i) = (int *)malloc(m*sizeof(int)

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
        A = read(A, i, j);

for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        B = read(B, i, j);

C = prod(A, B, n, m, k);

print(C, n, m);
}

int **read(int **x, int i, int j)
{
printf("Give value to store in cell [%d][%d]: ", i, j);
scanf("%d", &x[i][j]);

return x;
}

int **prod(int **x, int **y, int n, int m, int k)
{
int i, j, l, sum;
int **res;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        sum = 0;

        for (l = 0; l < m; l++)
            sum = sum + (x[i][l]*y[l][j]);

        res[i][j] = sum;
    }

return res;
}

void print(int **x, int r, int c)
{
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < c; j ++)
        printf("C[%d][%d]: %d\t", i, j, x[i][j]);

    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: What results do you get, and what results do you want? Welcome to Stackoverflow...Please take your time to Edit your Question to make it easier to follow and answer....See the Help guide

Comment: Oops, you're right i forgot, let me edit it real quick :)

Comment: Please point out where you're allocating memory for the return value in `prod`

Comment: It'd be easier to understand your data if you write the plain matrix instead of a list of coordinates and values.

Answer (score 0):

first understand the matrix without pointers

**Matrix multiplication without pointers**

int r1,r2,c1,c2;

int i,j,sum,k;

void matrixmul()

{

```
printf("Getting values for matrices");

printf("\n---------------------------");

printf("\n Enter the row for Matrix A: ");

scanf("%d",&r1);

printf("\n Enter the column for Matrix A: ");

scanf("%d",&c1);

printf("\n Enter the row for Matrix B: ");

scanf("%d",&r2);

printf("\n Enter the column for Matrix A: ");

scanf("%d",&c2);

int a[r1][c1];

int b[r2][c2];

int c[r1][c2];

if (!((c1==r2)&&(r1==c2)))

{

    printf("Row column miss matching so cannot do matrix multiplication");

}

else

{

    printf("\n A Matrix");

    printf("\n ---------");

    for (i=0;i<r1;i++)

      {

          for(j=0;j<c1;j++)

          {

              printf("\n Enter %d and %d value: ",i,j);

              scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);

          }

      }

    printf("\n B Matrix");

    printf("\n ---------");

    for (i=0;i<r2;i++)

      {

          for(j=0;j<c2;j++)

          {

              printf("\n Enter %d and %d value: ",i,j);

              scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);

          }

      }
}

for(i=0;i<c1;i++)

   {

       for(j=0;j<r2;j++)

       {

           for (k=0;k<r2;k++)

           {

               sum = sum + a[i][k]*b[k][j];

            }

            c[i][j] = sum;

            sum = 0;
       }

   }

printf("\nResultant Matrix");

printf("\n----------------\n");

for(i=0;i<r1;i++)

{

    for(j=0;j<c2;j++)

    {

        printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);

    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

}

void main()

{

```
matrixmul();
```

}

**Output**

Enter the row for Matrix A: 2

Enter the column for Matrix A: 3

Enter the row for Matrix B: 3

Enter the column for Matrix B: 2

A Matrix

---

Enter the 0 and 0 value:1

Enter the 0 and 1 value:2

Enter the 0 and 2 value:3

Enter the 1 and 0 value:3

Enter the 1 and 1 value:2

Enter the 1 and 2 value:11

B Matrix

---

Enter the 0 and 0 value:4

Enter the 0 and 1 value:5

Enter the 1 and 0 value:7

Enter the 1 and 1 value:8

Enter the 1 and 0 value:9

Enter the 1 and 1 value:10

Resultant Matrix

---

45      51
 125     141

Matrix with pointers-in this program 2D is declared using pointer variable and get the values for the 2D array and display the values

void main()

{

```
int r = 2, c = 3, i, j, count;

int *a[r];//while declaring the array as pointer its number of rows are specified

for (i=0; i<r; i++)

{

    a[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));//Allocate memory space for each row for 'c' columns

}


count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < r; i++)

{

    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)

        {

            scanf("%d",&a[i][j] ); 

        }   

}


for (i = 0; i < r; i++)

{

    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)

        {


           printf("%d\t ", a[i][j]);

        }

    printf("\n");

}
```

}

**Output**

3

2

1

1

2

3

3        2       1

1        2       3

The following is the final complete matrix multiplication using pointers

void input()

{

```
int r1, c1,r2,c2, i, j,k,sum;

printf("\n Enter the row for Matrix A: ");

scanf("%d",&r1);

printf("\n Enter the column for Matrix A: ");

scanf("%d",&c1);

printf("\n Enter the row for Matrix B: ");

scanf("%d",&r2);

printf("\n Enter the column for Matrix A: ");

scanf("%d",&c2);

if (!((c1==r2)&&(r1==c2)))

{

     printf("Row column miss matching so cannot do matrix multiplication");

}

else

{
    int *a[r1];

    int *b[r2];
    int *c[r1];

    for (i=0; i<r1; i++)

    {

        a[i] = (int *)malloc(c1 * sizeof(int));

    }

    for (i=0; i<r2; i++)

    {

        b[i] = (int *)malloc(c2 * sizeof(int));


    }

    for (i=0; i<r1; i++)

    {

        c[i] = (int *)malloc(c2 * sizeof(int));

    }

    printf("\n A Matrix");
    printf("\n ----------");

    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++)

        {

            for (j = 0; j < c1; j++)

                 {

                    printf("\n Enter the %d and %d value:",i,j);

                    scanf("%d",&a[i][j] ); 

                }   

        }
        printf("\n B Matrix");
        printf("\n ----------");

        for (i = 0; i < r2; i++)

            {

                for (j = 0; j < c2; j++)

                    {

                        printf("\n Enter the %d and %d value:",i,j);

                         scanf("%d",&b[i][j]); 

                      } 

                }

        for(i=0;i<c1;i++)

           {

                for(j=0;j<r2;j++)

                    {

                        for (k=0;k<r2;k++)

                            {

                                sum = sum + a[i][k]*b[k][j];

                            }

                         c[i][j] = sum;

                        sum = 0;
                     }

            }

        printf("\n Resultant Matrix");

        printf("\n------------------");

        for (i = 0; i < r1; i++)

            {

                for (j = 0; j < c2; j++)

                    {

                        printf("%d\t ", c[i][j]);

                     }

                printf("\n");

             }

    }
```

}

void main()
{

```
input();
```

}

**Output**

Enter the row for Matrix A: 2

Enter the column for Matrix A: 3

Enter the row for Matrix B: 3

Enter the column for Matrix B: 2

A Matrix

---

Enter the 0 and 0 value:1

Enter the 0 and 1 value:2

Enter the 0 and 2 value:3

Enter the 1 and 0 value:3

Enter the 1 and 1 value:2

Enter the 1 and 2 value:11

B Matrix

---

Enter the 0 and 0 value:4

Enter the 0 and 1 value:5

Enter the 1 and 0 value:7

Enter the 1 and 1 value:8

Enter the 2 and 0 value:9

Enter the 2 and 1 value:10

Resultant Matrix

---

45      51
 125     141

run the above program one by one understand it then convert the final program into function as per your required,Thank you

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly what you said and it worked :) It also helped me understand better what is actually going on :)